# Mapping multiple child properties

Tags: entity-framework-core, automapper

Having some Automapper headaches.  Any help appreciated!

```
public class ObjectA {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<ObjectB> ObjectBList {get; set;}
}

public class ObjectB {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ObjectAId { get; set; }
  public ObjectA Parent;

  public int ObjectCId { get; set; }
  public ObjectC SecondaryNavProperty {get; set;}
}

public ObjectADto {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int[] Children { get; set; }
}
```

How do I convert the DTO to a valid ObjectA, where ObjectBList is an array of ObjectB where each entry has Id set to one of the ObjectDto.Children properties.

I'm currently doing this:

```
configuration.CreateMap<ObjectADto , ObjectA >()
                .ForMember(destination => ObjectA.ObjectBList , options => options.MapFrom(source => source.Children.Select(detail => detail)))
```

but this isn't right because no where am I assing `ObjectB.Id` to the item in the `Children` array.  `ObjectB` exists as a .net core many-to-many table.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you expecting data to come from the database to populate `ObjectBList `? If so that's not going to happen and you shouldn't do that using Automapper. At best you will only be able to populate the Id of ObjectB as that is all you have in `ObjectADto.Children`

Comment: No, it didn't happen automatically.  I ended up writing code in .AfterMap to do a lot of the work.

Comment: Ideally mapping should be completely separate from getting the data from the database, you should always have the data first before doing the mapping, I've worked on a project that used mapping to get data and it had to be rewritten as among other things the performance was terrible.